# Custom error code for laravel form request

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have an endpoint I would like to post a bulk update request like this:

```
{
   "resources": [
      {
         "id": 5,
         "name": "ABC"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to prevent someone updating a resource they are not the owner of. I can create the following rule to prevent this:

```
'resources.*.id' => ['required', 'exists:resources,id,team_id,' . $this->team()->id],
```

I'd like to customize the error code so that I receive a `403` error code when this rule is violated. All other rules I am happy with the normal `422` error code.

I am aware I can customize the message in the `messages()` method. Is there something similar so I can return my own error code? At the moment I just get the standard `422` code.

I am also aware I could load all the team resources in the `authorize()` method, but I wonder if there is a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: have you made a separate class extending FormRequest, or are you directly validating from controller

Comment: I am extending FormRequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm a bit late, but hopefully, my answer can still help you or someone in the future.

You can see the Form Request Validation Class you created extends from `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`. Then if you look at the source code on the Laravel Framework, there is [a function to handle failed validation attempts](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b5300a1dba04614542c3eb2b342f5c07a89c4162/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L136).

So the solution, you can override the default `failedValidation` function in the Form Request Validation Class you created. Here is a sample code you can use:

```php
// ./app/Http/Requests/UpdateFooBarRequest.php

...
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class UpdateFooBarRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ...

    /**
     * Handle a failed validation attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator  $validator
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                    ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                    ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl())
                    ->status(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Credit: [Discussion from Laracasts - How to make a custom FormRequest error response in Laravel 5.5](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-make-a-custom-formrequest-error-response-in-laravel-55?page=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending FormRequest, then you can add your custom messages in the messages function,

```
public function messages() {
    $messages = [];

    foreach ($this->get('resources') as $key => $val) {
        $messages["resources.$key.id.exists"] = "The data :attribute"; // will send 'The data exists'
        $messages["resources.$key.id.required"] = "The data is :attribute";
    }

    return $messages;

}
```

#### #Edit: 2nd Part of Question

> If the authorize method returns false, an HTTP response with a 403 status code will automatically be returned and your controller method will not execute.
> [Source](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#authorizing-form-requests)

```
public function authorize()
{
    return false;
}
```

Then it will send 403 requests instead of 422.

Comment: Thanks, but will this customize the error code? I'd like to return a 403, not the standard 422.

Comment: I edited my question to make this more clear. I want to return a different error code for 1 particular rule. When the any resource id does not belong to the team then I'd like to respond with a 403 error.

Comment: If you want that then you need to handle it as normal or some other manual exception class then throw 403 error when you catch that exception

Comment: If you want I can give you an example, then all the above methods would be null hence deleted from the answer, Also you need to specify in detail that for which validation you want a specific message with 403 error in order for others to help